# Save last row number as variable after opening the workbook for the later use

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save the last row number used in a particular sheet at `Workbook_Open()` for the later use in other modules.
So far I have this code:

ThisWorkbook:

```
Public last_row as long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    last_row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox ("This is the last row number: " & last_row)
End Sub
```

I get the pop-up message correctly, like "This is the last row number: 25", when I open the workbook. This is a desired output.

Module 1:

```
Sub ABC()
    MsgBox ("This is the last row number: " & last_row)
End Sub
```

But when I run the Module 1, "This is the last row number: " message is what I get.

So, I am failing in storing the "*last_row*" variable as public. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need the last row with data or just the last row?

Comment: (1) "*it is not working*" is a very bad error description. What is the actual output in the message box and what do you expect to get? Are there any errors and where? (2) Always specify a worksheet when using `Cells`, `Range` or `Rows` etc. You missed that in `Rows.count` which should be `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.count`.

Comment: Bad Idea. Why do you want to store it in `Workbook_Open()`? Why not recalculate it at real time? What is the objective?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am doing this so that I resume the operations from `last_row + 1`, once I open the workbook.

Comment: Like I said it is a bad Idea. If there is a code error, the public variable will reset. I recommend recalculating it everythime

Comment: @SiddharthRout My objective is to Copy some data matching the criteria to other worksheet, after the data entry. For example, I have a survey results which I will paste or enter in one worksheet. Then I want to copy the newly entered data supporting some criteria, to other worksheet. For that I want to know the last used row to avoid repeating operations on old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, modify your code like this:

```
Sub ABC()
   MsgBox ("This is the last row number: " & ThisWorkbook.last_row)
End Sub
```

To use a public variable declared in ThisWorkbook module you must qualify it with the module name.

Notes:

1. You should enable Option Explicit in your VBE. It would have told you that last_row is not declared. A good habit to have;
2. Although this solution will work, I 100% agree with @Siddharth Rout that this approach is a conceptually bad idea - you will end up with an unstable (unpredictable) code.

There are many better ways to solve your problem; the simpest is - save your last row number to a cell on a hidden sheet.

Comment: Thanks! You are also write. I think I will use the simple solution after all.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is a bad idea and definitely not recommended. Public variables reset the moment there is an error.

Recalculate it every time you want to use it. You can do it in two ways

1. `lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` where `ws` is your worksheet object
2. Create a function if you do not want to write that "**long code** [pun intended :)]" every time

Paste this in a module

```
Function GetMeLastRow() As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to relevant sheet or pass it as a parameter

    With ws
        GetMeLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
End Function
```

And then use it like this

```
MsgBox GetMeLastRow
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this. Thanks!